# cascade="all-delete- orphan" was no longer referenced

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have been watching here about this exception but I cannot find the solution so I think to just paste my code just in case that there´s something wrong.
I´m receving this exception when I´m try to find the EvaluationSelectionCriteria entity.

```
Exception: org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-      orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.greenvalley.etendering.domain.Candidacy.evaluationSelectionCriterias 


 @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "candidacy_id", nullable = false)
@XmlElement
@JsonIgnore
@Getter
@Setter
private List<EvaluationSelectionCriteria> evaluationSelectionCriterias = new ArrayList<>();



@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "candidacy_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
@XmlTransient
@Getter
@Setter
private Candidacy candidacy;
```

Comment: This means, that you have replaced the persistent collection in your entity... i.e. you have called somewhere in your code `yourEntity.setEvaluationSelectionCriterias(whatever)`. This is not allowed since that replaces the collection initialized by entity manager. That collection is special type of a collection which tracks added and removed elements. You might think it should be `ArrayList` (since that is what you are initializing it to), but that is not true for persistent entities. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-persistent

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this issue by replacing my setXX method with something like this

```
public void setEvaluationSelectionCriterias(List<EvaluationSelectionCriteria> evaluationSelectionCriterias) {

if(this.evaluationSelectionCriterias == null) { //if not already initialized
  this.evaluationSelectionCriterias = evaluationSelectionCriterias;
} else {
  this.evaluationSelectionCriterias.clear();
  this.evaluationSelectionCriterias.addAll(evaluationSelectionCriterias);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that when dealing with @ManyToOne relationships @JoinTable seems to work better than @JoinColumn alone. Try something like this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
   name="candidacy_evaluation_search_criteria",
   joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="evaluation_selection_criteria", referencedColumnName="id") },
   inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="candidacy", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true) })
@XmlElement
@JsonIgnore
@Getter
@Setter
private List<EvaluationSelectionCriteria> evaluationSelectionCriterias = new ArrayList<>();
```

and

```
@ManyToOne(mappedBy = "evaluationSelectionCriterias")
@XmlTransient
@Getter
@Setter
private Candidacy candidacy;
```

As a side note, 'criteria' is plural of 'criterion', so your class name should be `EvaluationSelectionCriterion` and collection name `evaluationSelectionCriteria`.